# [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to ''

Tags: hibernate, hql

I was trying to get the repeated movies on the catalog.

In the catalog I have the id of the movies.

CatalogDaoImpl.class

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Movie> findMovies() {
        String query = "SELECT m.movie.id, count(m.movie.id)"
                + " from Catalog m group by m.movie.id"
                + " order by count(m.movie.id)";
        List<Movie> movies = getSession().createQuery(query).getResultList();

        return movies;
    }
```

When I try to use this dao, I get the next error:

```
[Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: 
[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.myapp.entities.Movie]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you declared the methods return type as `List<Movie>` but de facto you are quyering a list of `List<Object[]>`. This is because in your `SELECT` clause you specified `m.movie.id, count(m.movie.id)`.

If you want `Movie` objects you should `SELECT m.movie` ...

Comment: I understand you but what is the way to get "select id_movie count(id_movie) from catalog group by id_movie" in hql?

Comment: Change the method return type to List<Object[]>

Comment: Thanks, but its not possible to cast to List<Movie>. Any solution?

Comment: There is no solution. You want movie.id which is probably an Integer and count(m.movie.id) which is an long. Best you could do is to select m.movie, count ... so the first index of the array would be the movie.

Comment: I want the repeated movies on the Catalog table. I tried "SELECT m.movie, count(m.movie) from Movie m group by m.movie ORDER BY count(m.movie)" but it doesn't work